# Forcing a GStreamer pipeline to run in real time when encoding video

Tags: video, computer-vision, gstreamer, video-processing, frame-rate

Folks,

I'm testing a computer vision element in a GStreamer pipeline; my element receives a live video stream from a webcam and runs some image processing code on it and saves the results to a database. When compiled with a debug flag, it also updates the video stream with some debugging marks. For debugging and development, I also run it from recorded videos.

My pipeline for live debugging from a recorded video (it works):

```
 gst-launch filesrc location=test-16.avi ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! people-heatmap db-path=test-16.sqlite ! xvimagesink
```

When I try a "blind debug" (i.e., save the data to the database, but with no video output), I do:

```
 gst-launch filesrc location=test-16.avi ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! people-heatmap db-path=test-16.sqlite ! fakesink sync=true
```

notice the "sync=true" in the fakesink. Without it, the code runs in a very high framerate and my vision algorithm gets lost (as it depends on the system clock to run).

But, when I try to re-encode the debug-marked video to a file (for later analysis) with:

```
 gst-launch filesrc location=test-16.avi ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! people-heatmap db-path=test-16.sqlite ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! ffmux_avi ! filesink location="debug-test-16.avi"
```

my code runs at a high frame rate (which, I suppose, is the maximum supported by my CPU).

I assumed it was the same problem I solved with the "sync=true" in the blind-debug case, but putting this option in the filesink element got me nothing.

So, how can I force the entire pipeline to run in real time (according to the video frame rate) when encoding the video to a file?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I not sure I get it correctly, but you could try to use **tee** element ended with '*fakesink sync=true*' to get similar effect.

So, it will be something like:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=test-16.avi ! tee name=t ! queue \
  ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! people-heatmap db-path=test-16.sqlite \
  ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! ffmux_avi ! filesink location="debug-test-16.avi" t. \
  ! queue ! avidemux ! fakesink sync=true
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! As I understood, the tee element copies the stream to the mpeg encoder while holding the data flow to the limits given by the fakesink, so the entire pipeline runs in real time, preventing my wall-clock dependent element from getting lost.